# How to validate a generator?

Tags: typescript, zod

I want to create a job manager where each job gradually returns data of different types. The data goes through an interface that treats it as homogenous. Then some code on the other end figures out what to do with it.

Some of the data that comes through might be invalid, so I'm using `zod` to validate it and fail fast as possible.

Anyway, I've decided that the best way to implement this pattern is using a generator (I could also do it with observables). **How can I use `zod` to validate a generator and its output?**

Here is some made-up code that shows what I want to do:

```
const JobFunction = z
    .function().args()
    .returns(z.generator(SomeZodSchema))
//           ^ i made this up
```

Comment: No way to validate a generator without consuming it.

Comment: @vr. You can just wrap it as it is being consumed and validate the outputs.